# Map key literal that starts with @ in elixir

Tags: elixir

I'm writing some Elixir code that will make an HTTP POST request, where the body is a JSON document of options.  One of the properties starts with an `@` symbol.

Not possible:

```
json = %{ q: "foobar", @timestamp: 1234567890 } |> Poison.encode!
```

What is the correct way to write a map key literal which starts with `@`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want it to be treated as an atom you can do:

```
%{ :q => "foobar", :"@timestamp" => 1234567890 }
```

This is also valid:

```
json = %{ :"@timestamp" => 1234567890, q: "foobar" }
```

However this is not:

```
json = %{ q: "foobar", :"@timestamp" => 1234567890 }
** (SyntaxError) iex:5: syntax error before: "@timestamp"
```

You can also use a string as the key:

```
json = %{ "@timestamp" => 1234567890, q: "foobar" }
```